# Audible Books does not install my books into my iTunes and wants me to do it manually, I can't figure out how

Tags: itunes

Audible Books fails to install into iTunes
I am using a desktop with Windows 7  64 bit.    I have been downloading Audible Books for 3 years and have 85 installed.  Several months ago downloading them did not put them in iTunes and the system wants me to import them manually.    You start with   "C\Program Files\iTunes\
and add two lines..... I know I need to choose the destination for 64 bit, but I do not see iTunes and I do not know how to put this title into iTunes if I can locate it?  The folks at Audible wasted a lot of my time but were zero help!
How can I get these books into my computer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you got your answer, but I am running into the same problem. It used to always download into iTunes but now I have to manual import it--royal pain, especially when you have purchased several books with multiple downloads.

On my computer (Windows 7), Audible stores the downloaded books in **C:Users/Public Documents/Audible/Downloads**.

From iTunes you go to "File" then "Add File to Library" and find the folder where the downloads reside. If you are not sure where that is, try looking in the **C:Users/Public** file to see if you find it.

Once you have imported the file, iTunes seems to remember this folder and will default to it when you hit "Add File to Library". Then you should check your iTunes Audiobooks to see that it did import successfully.